# I've port forwarded, and can access this IIS server locally, why can't I see it online through my public IP?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, iis

I've been searching around, and am stumped. I have an IIS server: [image: IIS]

and I can access it locally: [image: IIS]

but when I'm outside the workplace, on a different connection, I cannot access it, I am using my public IP address followed by :35855 to attempt to do so. Why is this? I'll post as much info as I can below.

Correct bindings and ip.
[image: IIS]

Port forwarded correctly.
  [image: IIS]

I can give any other info on request if needed.

Comment: Use http://www.portchecktool.com/ to make sure that the internet can actually access your server.  Maybe you have some other firewall?

Comment: This must have something to do with it, it's saying all of my ports are closed. I recently installed Mcafee and it came with a firewall, I'm going to try uninstalling Mcafee and see what that does. Will report back

Comment: Before uninstalling, maybe try do disable the Mcafee firewall?

Comment: According to Mcafee, the firewall is disabled, although Windows claims it is active and being controlled by Mcafee, so I'm going to try a full uninstall, it takes seconds to reinstall anyway.

Comment: Weird, even with Mcafee uninstalled and my firewall disabled completely, all online port checkers are telling me my ports are closed.

Comment: Looks like the port forward is not forwarding properly. Which router do you have?

Comment: the ActionTec R1000H, I made another question in the meantime, asking why my ports are closed instead of this one.

Comment: @Zalmy As far as I can see, they're fine, what about you?
http://i.imgur.com/ltM2ISF.png
http://i.stack.imgur.com/YXJEX.png
http://i.imgur.com/7cRxGH6.png
http://i.imgur.com/eg0j3ye.png

DMZ disabled, firewall is NAT only, ports are forwarded to the host machines IP, etc.

Comment: How about, try to set the firewall to low?

Comment: Nada, still doesn't work, all ports appear as "closed", I've tried contacting my ISP and they just told me they only help with initial setup of an internet connection and that's it. :/

Comment: For testing try putting the the target host as the dmz host.

Comment: Attempted, all ports still closed, also tried restarting router again, to no avail. You've been here troubleshooting with me for a while, if you're getting a little annoyed at how long this is taking, you can stop

Comment: wait! Port 22 and 23 have opened after the restart, its something, right?

Comment: You can try this tool to see if the port is open http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/pUNbT1T.png

That's what I have been using, it claims port 22/23 are open, but in my router settings page, that is not the case
http://i.imgur.com/UR6nEXH.png

Comment: are you sure you're don't have double NAT ? DSL does your "ActionTec R1000H" router have a public IP?

Comment: The ActionTec has a public IP, it being the one shown in yougetsignal, I've had no problems with the same model router on different networks, but for some reason it won't open ports here, it IS a business network with about 25 connections, if it matters. Almost everyone is on a wired connection though. I am sure double NAT is not a problem.

Comment: can you make a "tracert  8.8.8.8" and give me the output?

Comment: @Zalmy http://snag.gy/qmsET.jpg

Comment: The issue here is that you have to port forward on the device that your router is connected. The modem also does nat.

Comment: So currently, I've port forwarded with the LAN IP "192.168.0.150" and "192.168.0.105" as they're both hosting 2 different servers, they are forwarding different ports. Was it incorrect to use those IPs when port forwarding?

Comment: No. The problem is that the router doesn't have a public ip. If you look at the tracert results, you see two 192.168 (private) networks.

Comment: Ah alright, thank you for your help, that was quite a bit of troubleshooting.